# PYQT5: some key presses not registering with keyPressEvent

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

**What my code is about**: I'm currently working on a project to create an image browser for all the images I have in my PC. I have created a database of all the images, this app will give me the ability to search through the database to find, and view and cycle through the images.

**What my problem is**: I'm trying to read left and right arrow key presses and connect them to a function that will change the shown image to the previous or next image in sequence. But for some reason the first two left-arrow presses don't register and none of the right-arrow presses register. Also, no other key presses are registering. My guess is that this is happening because the arrow keys are cycling through the widgets on screen. Need ideas on how I can fix this.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.main_widget = qtw.QWidget()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())
        self.main_widget.layout().setSpacing(0)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.image_label = qtw.QLabel(alignment=qtc.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(qtg.QPixmap(r'B:\Learning\Python\images\image.jpg'))
        self.viewer()
        self.menubar()
        self.main_widget.layout().addWidget(self.menu_widget)
        self.main_widget.layout().addWidget(self.viewer)
        self.main_widget.layout().setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.setStyleSheet("""* {
            background-color: #0d0d0d;
        }
        .QLabel {
            border-style: none;
        }
        .QMainWindow {
            border-style: none;
        }
        """)
        self.show()

    def menubar(self):
        self.menu_widget = qtw.QWidget()
        self.menu_widget.setLayout(qtw.QHBoxLayout())
        self.menu_widget.layout().setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.menu_widget.layout().setSpacing(0)
        self.menu_widget.layout().setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignLeft)
        import_btn = qtw.QPushButton('Import')
        browser_btn = qtw.QPushButton('Browser', clicked=self.browser_clicked)
        import_btn.setFixedWidth(70)
        browser_btn.setFixedWidth(70)
        self.menu_widget.layout().addWidget(import_btn)
        self.menu_widget.layout().addWidget(browser_btn)
        self.menu_widget.setStyleSheet("""
        QWidget {
            background-color: #1f1f1f;
        }
        .QPushButton {
            background-color: #1f1f1f;
            color: #fdf8ff;
            height: 50px;
            border-style: none;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .QPushButton::hover {
            background-color: white;
        }
        """)

    def viewer(self):
        self.viewer = qtw.QMainWindow()
        self.viewer.setCentralWidget(self.image_label)
        self.dock = qtw.QDockWidget('browser')
        # dock.setTitleBarWidget(qtw.QWidget(dock))
        self.dock.setStyleSheet('background-color: #1f1f1f; color: #c8cdc8')
        self.browser()
        self.dock.setWidget(self.browser_widget)
        self.dock.setFeatures(qtw.QDockWidget.DockWidgetClosable | qtw.QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable)
        self.viewer.addDockWidget(qtc.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.dock)

    def browser_clicked(self):
        if self.dock.isVisible():
            self.dock.hide()
        else:
            self.dock.show()
            if self.dock.isFloating():
                self.dock.setFloating(False)

    def browser(self):
        self.browser_widget = qtw.QMainWindow()
        self.browser_main_widget = qtw.QWidget()
        self.browser_widget.setCentralWidget(self.browser_main_widget)
        self.browser_main_widget.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())
        self.search_box = qtw.QWidget()
        self.search_box.setFixedHeight(int(0.15*self.height()))
        self.search_box.setLayout(qtw.QFormLayout())
        self.browser_main_widget.layout().addWidget(self.search_box)
        search_edit = qtw.QLineEdit()
        search_edit.setPlaceholderText('Enter search term(s)...')
        search_bar = qtw.QHBoxLayout()

        filter_options = ['tags', 'name', 'custom...']
        filter_option_combobox = qtw.QComboBox()
        filter_option_combobox.addItems(filter_options)
        filter_option_combobox.setCurrentIndex(0)
        filter_option_combobox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.custom_filters)

        search_btn = qtw.QPushButton('Search')
        search_bar.addWidget(filter_option_combobox)
        search_bar.addWidget(search_btn)
        self.search_box.layout().addRow(search_edit)
        self.search_box.layout().addRow(search_bar)

        browser_groupbox = qtw.QGroupBox('Browse')
        self.browser_main_widget.layout().addWidget(browser_groupbox)

        self.browser_widget.setStyleSheet(""".QLineEdit {
                background-color: #4d4d4d;
                color: #bbbcbb;
                border-style: none;
                height: 22px;
            }
            .QPushButton {
                background-color: #ed2553;
                color: #fdf8ff;
            }
            .QComboBox {
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
                height: 20px;
            }
            """)

    def custom_filters(self, value):
        if value == 'custom...':
            pass

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == qtc.Qt.Key_Left:
            print(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*Change the `self.image_label.setPixmap(qtg.QPixmap(r'B:\Learning\Python\images\image.jpg'))` line (line 14) with a link to an actual image to see the code working with an actual image.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you're adding widgets that can get focus, while the "viewer" doesn't have a focus, nor it can accept one by keyboard/mouse if not programmatically.

The result is that when the window is shown the first time, Qt will try to set the focus on the widget that can accept one within the central widget, but since there's none, any keyboard event is ignored. Whenever you try to use the arrow keys, then, Qt will use the "keyboard navigation" mode, and will find the first widget that can accept focus (the "search" button, if you go left), making the event accepted, and thus not propagated to the main window; going further, if you go left once more, the "tags" combo will get focused, again accepted and not propagated.

A temporary workaround could be to ensure that the buttons and line edit only get focus by clicking (but buttons should probably not get focus at all):

```
def browser(self):
    # ...
    search_edit.setFocusPolicy(qtc.Qt.ClickFocus)
    filter_option_combobox.setFocusPolicy(qtc.Qt.ClickFocus)
    search_btn.setFocusPolicy(qtc.Qt.ClickFocus)
```

Then, at the end of the `__init__`, you should set the focus on the viewer, possibly after setting a StrongFocus policy, which will ensure that it will get keyboard focus after being clicked, if the focus is on another widget (like the line edit, that will obviously accept all arrow keys events).

```
    self.viewer.setFocusPolicy(qtc.Qt.StrongFocus)
    self.viewer.setFocus()
```

Unfortunately, that wouldn't be a complete solution, as there are other issues with your implementation.

First of all, QMainWindow should rarely be used as a child widget (especially for a dock): it's a very specialized type of QWidget that has its own private layout and event management, which could result in unexpected behavior.
Instead of adding a QMainWindow to the dock and as the main viewer, use simple QWidgets.

Then, "global" keyboard events like these should be managed with care, as they could disrupt standard usage or could be "eaten" by child widget (meaning that those widgets accept the event and don't propagate it to their parent). This is most important for a widget such as a QMainWindow, that has very special implementations since it can also include menus and toolbars that could require keyboard interaction.

A possible solution is to use a QAction, set a proper shortcut for it, and **add the action** to the main window (this is mandatory, otherwise it will never be triggered).
This approach has the benefit that if the currently focused widget actually handles arrow keys, it will use them without propagation (which is important for keyboard navigation in a line edit), otherwise the shortcut will trigger the linked QAction.

```
class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.goLeftAction = qtw.QAction('Go left', self)
        self.goLeftAction.setShortcut('left')
        self.goLeftAction.triggered.connect(self.goLeft)
        self.addAction(self.goLeftAction)
        self.goRightAction = qtw.QAction('Go right', self)
        self.goRightAction.setShortcut('right')
        self.goRightAction.triggered.connect(self.goRight)
        self.addAction(self.goRightAction)

    def goLeft(self):
        print('going left')

    def goRight(self):
        print('going right')
```

<sup>PS: be careful with generic stylesheets set on widgets that can have children (like you did with `self.dock`): they often have unexpected results for complex widgets like scroll areas (including the popup of a QComboBox). In these situations it's always better to use proper [selector types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types), possibly with appropriate pseudo states.</sup>